# Vis.js Gap between Node and its border

Tags: vis.js-network, vis.js

Using Vis.js I want to Generate something where in there is a gap between the [Circular image](http://visjs.org/examples/network/nodeStyles/circularImages.html) and the Node border

**Sample**: [image]

I cannot find anything at the Vis.js documentation for such a modification, can anyone guide me for it?

---

[vis.js GitHub issue report](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/3902)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to achieve this unfortunelly. The `color` option only accepts one border and you can't make use of CSS since Vis is built using canvas, not SVG.

What you can do to achieve this is crop your image in a circular shape with some transparent padding to make the gap. And then vis would add the black border for you.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that.do not add border option in node.you can add circular border in afterDrawing event.

```
network.on("afterDrawing", function (ctx) {
            var imageSize= 21;
            var nodeId = 1;
            var nodePosition = network.getPositions([nodeId]);
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#006bb3';
            ctx.lineWidth = 4;
            ctx.circle(nodePosition[nodeId].x, nodePosition[nodeId].y, imageSize+5);
            ctx.stroke();
})
```